# Reskit Post Request Mapping Simple Array of Int

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I'm trying to post a request with an array of int

> [1, 2, 3, ..]

I cannot figure out how to do it.

```
RKObjectMapping * ordersRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
// Missing the right line here
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addRequestDescriptor:[RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:ordersRequestMapping
                                                                                                objectClass:[NSArray class]
                                                                                                rootKeyPath:nil
                                                                                                     method:RKRequestMethodPOST]];
```

So far I know it needs "fromKeyPath" to nil

Comment: Don't use restkit for that, just create the results and send it

Comment: @wain I have a Response mapped with Restkit. So I have to map that Request too and post it, but i don't know the way to map that Request.

Comment: What have you tried adding for the request mapping detail then? You don't give any info about the array of objects you're mapping and what it's currently sending